# How to add React.js to an existing .NET Core

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, api, asp.net-core

I am just wondering if there are any other professional ways to use React with .NET Core. I already have a .NET core API ready with DB connection, data, and controllers. All I need is some way to add react as a client for this project instead of using React template that we have to select in the beginning.

I found a few things on youtube but not sure if those are the best practices or something I would do in production.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

start with `create-react-app` and have it as completely separate thing.
that way your react app doesn't know nor care what API is - all it cares about is api endpoints.

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

Comment: I thought about it, just not sure if it’s best practice or something that people would do in production.

Comment: its a normal practice used in production. for more advanced needs, you might need to eject webpack configurations and setup some things you might need but until you have a need - there is no point in touching it. `create-react-app` is a common starting point.

Comment: Thanks for the answer